# How can I get Beautiful soup html parser to be the same code displayed when I click inspect in Chrome?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

So basically I am trying to build a web scraper to find the reviews of products in an aliexpress site. When I parse the html code though, the parsed code is not the same as the code I see in the inspect window in Chrome. I am unable to find the review section in the code I have parsed. How am I able to parse the code exactly as I see it in the inspect window?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup  # HTML data structure
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq  # Web client

# URl to web scrap from.
page_url = "https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000042292255.html? 
spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.4a253632RWxaLa&algo_pvid=c73bf552-ce47-43f6-9abb- 
b4a994eeaa01&algo_expid=c73bf552-ce47-43f6-9abb-b4a994eeaa01-0&btsid=2c594979-4027-410a-a7a4- 
7246ce06ade7&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_7,searchweb201603_53"

# opens the connection and downloads html page from url
uClient = uReq(page_url)

# parses html into a soup data structure to traverse html
# as if it were a json data type.
page_soup = soup(uClient.read(), "html.parser")
uClient.close()
```

Comment: If the site loads content using javascript then you'll need to use Selenium or something similar which can execute javascript. Do a search here on SO for numerous related posts.

Answer (score 0):

It's dynamically generated, and you can crawl it by rendering. Here's an example of simplified_scrapy and pyppeteer.

```
from simplified_html.request_render import RequestRender
req = RequestRender({ 'executablePath': '/Applications/chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome'})
def callback(html,url,data):
  from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc 
  doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
  print (doc.title)
req.get('https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000042292255.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.4a253632RWxaLa&algo_pvid=c73bf552-ce47-43f6-9abb-b4a994eeaa01&algo_expid=c73bf552-ce47-43f6-9abb-b4a994eeaa01-0&btsid=2c594979-4027-410a-a7a4-7246ce06ade7&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_7,searchweb201603_53',callback)
```

Result:

```
{'tag': 'title', 'html': 'Note 7 pro smartphones 4G LTE celulares 4GB RAM 64GB ROM quad core 13MP camera 18:9 IPS Android mobile phones face ID unlocked-in Cellphones from Cellphones &amp; Telecommunications on AliExpress'}
```

You can get the examples of simplified_scrapy [here](https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo)